# The problem with rewriting the code from Matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab

I am new to Python and I am trying to convert and modify the following code from Matlab to python:

```
function A = alg_a(RGBimage, n)
[row, column, d] = size(RGBimage);
if (d==3)
 HSVimage = rgb2hsv(RGBimage);
 V = HSVimage(:,:,3);
else
 V =double(RGBimage)/255;
end
V=V(:);
[Vsorted, ix] = sort(V);
s = (row*column)/n;
i=0;
h=[];
while (i < n)
 i=i+1;
 z = Vsorted(((floor(s*(i-1))+1)):floor(s*i));
 Vstart = (s*(i-1))/(row*column);
 Vstop = (s*i)/(row*column);
 r=z-z(1);
 f = (1/n)/(r(size(r,1)));
 g = r*f;
 if(isnan(g(1)))
   g = r + Vstop;
 else
   g = g + Vstart;
 end
 h=vertcat(h,g);
end
m(ix)=h;
m=m(:);
if(d==3)
 HSVimage(:,:,3) = reshape(m,row,column);
 A=hsv2rgb(HSVimage);
else
 A=reshape(m,row,column);
end
return;
end
```

This function implements the SMQT image preprocessing algorithm, and my problem is that I don't really understand how it works, which is why I'm stuck here:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

img = cv2.imread("16.bmp")
n = 8

(row, column, dim) = img.shape
if dim == 3:
    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    V = hsv_img[:, :, 2]
else:
    V = img / 255

V = V.flatten(order='F')
Ix = V.argsort()[::-1]
V_sorted = V[Ix]
s = int(row*column/n)
i = 0
h = []

while i < n:
    i += 1
    z = V_sorted[math.floor(s*(i-1))+1:math.floor(s*i)]
    z = np.array(z)
    V_start = (s*(i-1))/(row*column)
    V_stop = (s * i) / (row * column)
    r = z - z[0]
    f = (1 / n) / r[len(r)-1]
    g = r * f

    if math.isnan(g[0]):
        g = r + V_stop
    else:
        g = g + V_start

    if len(h) == 0:
        h = g
    else:
        h = np.vstack((h, g))
M = np.array([])
M[Ix] = h
M = M.flatten(order='F')
if dim == 3:
    hsv_img = np.reshape(M, row, column)
    img_res = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
else:
    img_res = np.reshape(M, row, column)
cv2.imwrite('16_smqt', img_res)
```

It seems that I wrote a code similar in functionality, but it does not work, and I haven't any idea why. The Matlab code was taken by me from the article, so I have no doubt that it works. Please help me find inaccuracies in my translation from Matlab to python.

Comment: I would advise you to learn Numpy. It helps a lot in dealing with matrices and numerical problems.

Comment: Where exactly is the issue?